# A Non editable UITableView section?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView with 3 sections.  The top two sections are static, and the third can be manipulated by the user.  By overriding the commitEditingStyle method, I can remove entries as needed from section 3.  However, doing this makes the Delete button appear on the cells in sections 0 and 1, even though I only execute the code when the selected cell is in section 3.

I feel like it's confusing if the delete button can be brought up on sections 0 and 1 even though the code doesn't do anything.  Is there any way to set sections 0 and 1 so that left->right swipes don't set those sections editable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` in the dataSource